# Quality of triangle

Tags: triangles

I am currently reading a paper called "[Indoor Localization for Bluetooth Low Energy Devices Using Weighted Off-set Triangulation Algorithm](https://www.ion.org/publications/abstract.cfm?articleID=14720)".

Now they use 3 reference points (APs) to triangulate the position of a person. If they find more than 3 reference points, they select the three best reference points.

To select the three best reference points they first look at the RSSI (received signal strength). Secondly they somehow calculate $W_r$ which indicates the quality of the triangle the three reference points defines.

$W_r$ is controlled by:
- the shape of the triangle
- the value of the distance ratio (which I think is the length of each side to each other, like L1/L2, L2/L3, L3/L1)

Now I find now way to calculate $W_r$ and wanted to ask if there is like a equation do this?

Comment: min length / max length

Comment: @R.Emery this would not definitely describe the shape of the triangle

Comment: I thought you wanted the quality of the triangle

Comment: @R.Emery yes, but it should be defined by - the shape of the triangle - the value of the distance ratio, and the shape would at least require one angle?

Comment: you need a metric. what defines how "good" or "bad" the triangle is?

Comment: yes, because how I understood the paper, the median euclidean error can be no larger than half the length of the side of the triangle, so a shorter triangle side and a equal side length of all three sides would be optimal.